# Mapshaper fails when converting files to .topojson due to file size?

Tags: geojson, topojson, limitations, mapshaper

I have a .gejson file that's about **378 meg (378,776k)**
and I'm trying to **convert it to topojson**.

I was successful with files that sized to about **262 meg**
but files greater than that failed leaving the error:

```
Error: "toString()" failed
at Buffer.toString (buff.js:480:11)
etc....
```

I'm using the command line format: 
ex)

```
mapshaper - i bigfile.geojson -o little.json format=topojson
```

and I'm starting to think that this is a buffering issue for memory that needs to be changed/tweeked.

What exactly do I  need  for files >~262 meg?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is related to the file size. It seems that mapshaper hits node's default memory limit if the file is too big.

From the [Node FAQ](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-memory-limit-on-a-node-process):

> by default v8 has a memory limit of 512MB on 32-bit systems, and 1.4GB
>   on 64-bit systems. The limit can be raised by setting
>   --max_old_space_size to a maximum of ~1024 (~1 GB) (32-bit) and ~4096 (~4GB) (64-bit), but it is recommended that you split your single
>   process into several workers if you are hitting memory limits.

Assuming that you're on Linux or OS X, you may try to increase Node's memory hard limit with a command like this:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 $(which mapshaper) - i bigfile.geojson -o little.json format=topojson
```

Also, I haven't tried it, but I've heard that Firefox can handle large strings as well. So an alternative solution could be using Mapshaper GUI on Firefox.

Comment: I tried this and got ```[ -n "$NODENV_DEBUG" ] && set -x
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string```. I was hoping running mapshaper-xl would help but still errors.